ChatGoogleGenerativeAI not working with tools in Langchain
I am trying to bind a DuckDuckGo search tool to ChatGoogleGenerativeAI. It is not working as expected and I am getting empty response in content when I try invoke the llm. Following is my code.
from langchain_google_genai import ChatGoogleGenerativeAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain_community.tools import DuckDuckGoSearchRun

load_dotenv()

search = DuckDuckGoSearchRun()

llm = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(model="gemini-1.5-flash", verbose=True)
llm_with_tools = llm.bind_tools([search])

response = llm_with_tools.invoke('Which is largest state in India')

print(response)

After executing this I get following response:
content='' additional_kwargs={'function_call': {'name': 'duckduckgo_search', 'arguments': '{"query": "Which is largest state in India"}'}} response_metadata={'prompt_feedback': {'block_reason': 0, 'safety_ratings': []}, 'finish_reason': 'STOP', 'safety_ratings': [{'category': 'HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH', 'probability': 'NEGLIGIBLE', 'blocked': False}, {'category': 'HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT', 'probability': 'NEGLIGIBLE', 'blocked': False}, {'category': 'HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT', 'probability': 'NEGLIGIBLE', 'blocked': False}, {'category': 'HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT', 'probability': 'NEGLIGIBLE', 'blocked': False}]} id='run-9b206745-4b1a-4600-b66c-fd874004f5e0-0' tool_calls=[{'name': 'duckduckgo_search', 'args': {'query': 'Which is largest state in India'}, 'id': '573e38e8-9985-4b23-99a8-b915f4d2c1b8', 'type': 'tool_call'}] usage_metadata={'input_tokens': 72, 'output_tokens': 22, 'total_tokens': 94}



llm.invoke() does not actually call a Langchain Tool. It only generates a ToolCall as part of the response's .tool_calls property. This ToolCall then needs to be manually invoked on a Tool.
See here:
https://python.langchain.com/docs/how_to/tool_results_pass_to_model/
https://python.langchain.com/docs/how_to/tool_calling/#defining-tool-schemas
